# Bootstrap column goes way down and out of container in ipad portrait

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I'm trying to align 4 bootstrap columns side by side. On ipad landscape view they are side by side two by two. But on ipad portrait the 3rd column goes way down. I've spent too many hours of the day trying to get this to work correctly without any luck.

Can anyone advise my on this?

```css
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device- width: 1024px) {
  .cv-box {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    float: left !important;
    width: 45% !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 text-center">
    <h1 class="team-lead" id="team">The Team</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="container the-team">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3  cv-box">
      <h3>SomeName</h3>

      <img src="/assets/BOS.jpg" class="portfolio-img img-responsive">
      <p class="cv">ntelligentsia mumblecore ethical yr, four dollar toast cliche hexagon waistcoat kinfolk. Enamel pin chia tumeric trust fund. Fap sriracha hot chicken, squid affogato brunch pok pok chicharrones normcore la croix typewriter offal fam pabst umami.
        Helvetica activated charcoal whatever, butcher air plant kale chips scenester before they sold out mustache kitsch authentic bespoke fashion axe meggings.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3  cv-box">
      <h3>SomeName</h3>

      <img src="/assets/BOS.jpg" class="portfolio-img img-responsive">
      <p class="cv">ntelligentsia mumblecore ethical yr, four dollar toast cliche hexagon waistcoat kinfolk. Enamel pin chia tumeric trust fund. Fap sriracha hot chicken, squid affogato brunch pok pok chicharrones normcore la croix typewriter offal fam pabst umami.
        Helvetica activated charcoal whatever, butcher air plant kale chips scenester before they sold out mustache kitsch authentic bespoke fashion axe meggings.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3  cv-box">
      <h3>SomeName</h3>

      <img src="/assets/BOS.jpg" class="portfolio-img img-responsive">
      <p class="cv">ntelligentsia mumblecore ethical yr, four dollar toast cliche hexagon waistcoat kinfolk. Enamel pin chia tumeric trust fund. Fap sriracha hot chicken, squid affogato brunch pok pok chicharrones normcore la croix typewriter offal fam pabst umami.
        Helvetica activated charcoal whatever, butcher air plant kale chips scenester before they sold out mustache kitsch authentic bespoke fashion axe meggings.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3  cv-box">
      <h3>SomeName</h3>

      <img src="/assets/BOS.jpg" class="portfolio-img img-responsive">
      <p class="cv">ntelligentsia mumblecore ethical yr, four dollar toast cliche hexagon waistcoat kinfolk. Enamel pin chia tumeric trust fund. Fap sriracha hot chicken, squid affogato brunch pok pok chicharrones normcore la croix typewriter offal fam pabst umami.
        Helvetica activated charcoal whatever, butcher air plant kale chips scenester before they sold out mustache kitsch authentic bespoke fashion axe meggings.</p>
    </div>
```

**Update**

I'm only using `col-xs-12 col-md-3`now so this is looking ok in smaller views but you can see the ongoing problem for larger views in the screenshot below.

here is a screenshot of the problem, as you can see, one of the columns is pushed below the others.
[image]

Comment: Why do you have `col-md-6` and `col-md-3` in a class tag? That might be your problem.

Comment: Hi no it's not that, it was an typo

Comment: could you edit your answer then? :3

Comment: I did, changed `col-md-6` to `col-sm-6`

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of the problem? I don't fully understand it.

Comment: Hi, I added a screenshot, this is working ok for smaller views but in larger views the columns adds up like in the screenshot.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `margin`?

Comment: Then the columns are all together in one row.. but sticking to each other with no space between them... I don´t want that, it needs to have space between the columns... thats is basically the problem

Comment: I'm not at my pc atm. But try to use a div around the cv-box div but give this div the col-* class and the desired padding. I hope I was clear.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll check it in few minutes

Comment: Thank you it works :), put that as an answer and I can mark it

Answer (score 0):

The container should be BEFORE class="row". Column team-load should have its own row.

```
<div class="container the-team">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 text-center">
    <h1 class="team-lead" id="team">The Team</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3  cv-box">
      <h3>SomeName</h3>

      <img src="/assets/BOS.jpg" class="portfolio-img img-responsive">
      <p class="cv">ntelligentsia mumblecore ethical yr, four dollar toast cliche hexagon waistcoat kinfolk. Enamel pin chia tumeric trust fund. Fap sriracha hot chicken, squid affogato brunch pok pok chicharrones normcore la croix typewriter offal fam pabst umami.
        Helvetica activated charcoal whatever, butcher air plant kale chips scenester before they sold out mustache kitsch authentic bespoke fashion axe meggings.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3  cv-box">
      <h3>SomeName</h3>

      <img src="/assets/BOS.jpg" class="portfolio-img img-responsive">
      <p class="cv">ntelligentsia mumblecore ethical yr, four dollar toast cliche hexagon waistcoat kinfolk. Enamel pin chia tumeric trust fund. Fap sriracha hot chicken, squid affogato brunch pok pok chicharrones normcore la croix typewriter offal fam pabst umami.
        Helvetica activated charcoal whatever, butcher air plant kale chips scenester before they sold out mustache kitsch authentic bespoke fashion axe meggings.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3  cv-box">
      <h3>SomeName</h3>

      <img src="/assets/BOS.jpg" class="portfolio-img img-responsive">
      <p class="cv">ntelligentsia mumblecore ethical yr, four dollar toast cliche hexagon waistcoat kinfolk. Enamel pin chia tumeric trust fund. Fap sriracha hot chicken, squid affogato brunch pok pok chicharrones normcore la croix typewriter offal fam pabst umami.
        Helvetica activated charcoal whatever, butcher air plant kale chips scenester before they sold out mustache kitsch authentic bespoke fashion axe meggings.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3  cv-box">
      <h3>SomeName</h3>

      <img src="/assets/BOS.jpg" class="portfolio-img img-responsive">
      <p class="cv">ntelligentsia mumblecore ethical yr, four dollar toast cliche hexagon waistcoat kinfolk. Enamel pin chia tumeric trust fund. Fap sriracha hot chicken, squid affogato brunch pok pok chicharrones normcore la croix typewriter offal fam pabst umami.
        Helvetica activated charcoal whatever, butcher air plant kale chips scenester before they sold out mustache kitsch authentic bespoke fashion axe meggings.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```